# Not able to import jar files in JSP code

Tags: java, jsp, jar, glassfish, executable-jar

I have jar files which I constructed using command
**jar -cf Generic.jar /java/mypackage/*.class**
There are three classes in the Generic.jar
mypackage is the name of package I named so as to include my class files and create a jar file.
latter I copied the Generic.jar in the **WEB-INF/lib** of Glassfish

In JSP I imported these jar files using

```
 <%@ page import="java.mypackage.GenericTree;" %>
 <%@ page import="java.mypackage.GenericTree1111;" %>
 <%@ page import="java.mypackage.GenericTree2222;" %>
```

But I am getting the following error. Can anyone suggest whats going wrong?

```
  HTTP Status 500 -

  type Exception report

  message

  descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this         request.

  exception

  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/mypackage/GenericTree

 note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish     Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 logs.
  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1
```

Comment: Try looking at the log files, as suggested at the bottom of your error message, to see what's going on.  This message just tells you that there was an error, not what the error was.

Comment: Would you confirm that the classes declare their package as "package java.mypackage;"?

Comment: Yes, I have included the package java.mypackage; in all my *.java files.

Comment: I've had the same problem, checked paths put library WEB-INF/lib directory. But solve this problem with rebooting of tomcat server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Are you sure your command succeeded? It does not work for me when the path starts with slash. So, first remove leading slash, i.e. command should look like the following: `jar -cf Generic.jar java/mypackage/*.class`
2. Package name that starts from word `java` is not for you. It is for JDK classes only. Such classes cannot be loaded by regular class loader, only by bootstrap one. So, rename your package. It should look like `com.mycompany.myprogram.foo.bar`
3. Now create the jar file using command I wrote and then test the result: run `jar vft` and see that output looks like

   1612 Thu Feb 03 14:44:34 IST 2011 com/mycompany/myprogram/Hello.class

Pay attention on the path. It must contain your package.

If everything is working copy your jar under WEB-INF/lib and enjoy. Good luck.